# Do we need more reviewers?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-queue

I was not logged in for some reason (maybe the cookie expired or something) when I click my bookmark to the C.SE review queue. This is what I saw:

[image: Complete review queue]

This is all the review tasks that are available for anyone who hasn't done them yet. Once logged in, they all say zero tasks available for me.

What I find a bit concerning is that there are 16 close vote reviews pending. I don't think we have anywhere near the problem as on the [SO close queue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE1Hj.png) However, I feel like there being 16 posts just sitting there taking days to get the necessary close votes is not necessarily acceptable.

In part, I'm urging all the users over 3,000 rep to go through that review queue regularly (at least once every two days).

I'm also asking if others think this might be an increasing problem. [EL&U is in a similar boat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDTbN.png). [Skeptics has only 1 in theirs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viUoK.png). [BH has only 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAg8Z.png).

Comment: Maybe you just happened to see it at an above average queue length. It was at 8 for me today, which is only slightly higher than normal.

Comment: Also a number of old Christian identity questions were flagged which boosted the numbers.

Comment: @curiousdannii Do you mean there were 8 that you were able to review or did you open the page in private mode (imitate logging out then seeing what the page reports). But you might have a point. Flimzy vtc'd on about five or six old posts in the last few days.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm thinking now that perhaps what I'm seeing is more complicated than that. Some of those posts may only have one or two vtc's but the community at large does not want to vtc them, so they have voted to leave open, dutifully doing their review tasks, but the votes still need to expire. I guess knowing when a question leaves the review queue by way of not being vtc'd would help me see what is going on.

Comment: It now says 19 posts in the close review at C.SE.

Comment: Only 3 for me currently. 19 if I'm not logged in, which I assume means that I've voted on 16 of the ones in the queue.

Comment: Strictly speaking an answer and not a comment: yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think we're doing okay. I don't think I can remember any times when my close votes have expired on this site, unlike how they have on other sites; I don't mean when a question goes through the review process and enough people disagree with me that the questions stay open, I'm talking about when a question accumulates a few downvotes but not quickly enough that it can get closed before the first ones expire. If that doesn't happen here then we're doing fine!

(Now it could be that we're only doing fine because the mods are jumping in at the last moment to close them. But I haven't heard any of them say that they think we need more.)

Answer (score -1):

More of a comment than an answer but it became way too long.

I agree with Neil, I like trying to help out on the site (not sure my efforts at reviewing are actually all that good, I skip quite a lot because I'm not sure what to do about them). Point is that questions and answers generally don't get that much rating on this site: it seems to suffer from a lack of voting.

For comparison I've asked 2 questions (and accepted answers) and answered 1 question on Skeptics.SE. I got more than 200 reputation on top of the starting 101: I'm about 303 at time of writing. I've got a pretty solidly positive record on Christianity.SE (1 closed question, 1 duplicate question, 1 question which after extensive editing I managed to get reopened) but after asking 26 questions (23 positive scored, 3 zeros), giving 12 answers (11 positive scores, 1 zeros) and doing plenty of edits, voting, reviewing etc. I'm at 1039 (at time of writing). To be fair I've burned 100 in bounties but 1139 doesn' make much difference. For the effort put in it is clearly much easier to get reputation on other sites. I've certainly poured 10s of times the time and effort into this site than over at Skeptics.

There is a natural through put of people on a site like this. I would imagine there are less than 20 regularly active members with enough reputation to work on close votes (and only about half of them actually seem to). This site due to its topic tends to build up a lot of bad questions. It's a problem. I don't know what the solution is, I certainly doubt that the standard stackexchange moderation reputation requirements will be changed just for this site but there you go.

Comment: I think, perhaps, your questions on Skeptics are an exception to the rule. Your one answer is pretty good though. On EL&U I have 1,400 rep because I usually only participate in questions that are in the hot list (those questions on the right there >>>). More traffic means more votes. Now we are in territory where rep does not necessarily imply that you understand the site guidelines. As you've said yourself about this site, you have over 1000 rep, but still skip review tasks because you aren't sure what to do, if anything. So I think the 3K rep mark for close reviews is good.

Comment: But if only half of the 20 regulars that can close vote don't ever, then I think there is a bit of a problem.

Comment: True but there are obvious close questions. Although I might not be fabulous at nuance and would skip say 1/2 the time. The obviously bad question would get closed a lot faster if people like me could participate. I don't know maybe there could be some kind of tip-it-over-the-edge system. For instance if users over 1000 could vote to close/reopen if there were already 2+ or 3+ votes to close/reopen it might speed things along when it is obvious.

Comment: @fedsbend Also look at your own profile on both sites. Your questions on Skeptics are recieved on average with a score of ~7.8. You only have 1 question out of 38 above that score on Christianity.SE - a site on which you are one of the top users. I think that says something about how easy it is to get reputation on these sites.

Comment: I have many questions above 7 votes on C.SE. You must mean something else. My top four questions on Skeptics ended up on the hot question list. None of my questions on this site ended up on the hot list. But in general, perhaps you are right that people do not vote enough on this site. The best policy is to be really liberal with voting. If there was research involved, it's easy to understand, is on-topic, and answers the question, then upvote right away. If it doesn't downvote, at least half the time, making leeway for cases where a downvote won't help.

Comment: You are quite right! I think I mistook recent questions for votes.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the 3000 rep prerequisite should be lowered. I would not mind helping with close votes but I doubt I'll be hitting 3000 rep anytime soon.

Comment: Oh that's only like five to ten good answers. You can do it ;)